# enforce ti redirect to Route that has a dynamic route after model for context is fully loaded

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a route showing posts list (PostsRoute)

and I want PostsIndexRoute to be redirected to

PostRoute(not PostsRoute, representing A post) with context of last post.

My app's layout is [image]

So I wrote a PostsIndex route like this

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    redirect: function() {
          var p = this.modelFor('posts').get('lastObject');
          this.transitionTo('post', p);
    }
});
```

When I enter /posts/ first time, redirection doesn't work.

(because models for Posts are not populated immediately.)

But second time for entering /posts/. Redirection works well.

(because models for Posts are now populated)

How do I enforce transition works AFTER the model for context is fully loaded?

(I'm using ember-data for model handling.)

Comment: I also tried 'var p = App.Post.find().get('lastObject');' but I results same behavior

Comment: Could you put together a little jsFiddle for this please?

Comment: It's database related so I don't think jsFiddle can show my problem..

Comment: Here is my project's git [link](https://github.com/synthresin/synthkr.git) It's using rails 3 and ember-data

Comment: my ember codes are in app/assets/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behavior you see came from 2 bugs :

- One in ember-data [#587](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/587), this prevent the records array to be loaded only when the data from the server are loaded. With the fix in [#735](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/735) this bug should be fixed.
- One in ember [#2116](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2116), this one make the redirect block call before the model is loaded

When both of them will be fixed, you should not encounter any bug with this.

Answer (score 0):

As you say in the question, the problem is that the recent posts aren't loaded by the time you go to the route. I see three options:

#### Pre-Load in App Setup

One common solution would be to instantiate and fetch the recent posts in the application setup and show a spinner until they're available.

#### Load in Posts/Index

Another, slightly more sophisticated option would be to have the `posts.index` state show a spinner, fetch the recent posts, and redirect to the most recent one when it's availalble.

#### Redirect to `/posts/last`

Add a new route for `/posts/last` that acts mostly like the `PostShow` route but fetches the last few models and selects the `lastObject`.

Comment: "redirect to the most recent one when it's availalble." How would you recommend doing this -- observing model.isLoaded?

Comment: Didn't work for me -- seems that if it was loaded it would transition to the new route too early and cause an error. The only safe place to transition that I've found is `didInsertElement` in the `View`. Perhaps I'm missing something